# :focus on ie6 with csshover3.htc

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

i try to use csshover3.htc on ie6  for input:focus but fail. Does :focus work on ie6 with csshover3.htc workaround?

Comment: This is going to be very difficult to get right. Ask yourself if it's worth the effort to get such an edge-case style working in such an old browser. I certainly wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no 100% acceptable solution and most fixes rely on Javascript to hack (fake) support into the browser. I'd recommend not bothering as the time taken to hack the support in for input:focus will not be worth it...besides IE6 is already in the "dying" phase of its lifetime.

But, if you are the peristent type then you might want to try [IE7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)